# SwiftUI Binding property of View Type

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have created PopupView like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct PopupView<Content>: View where Content: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @Binding var viewForPresentation: Content
    var content: () -> Content
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            content()
                .blur(radius: isPresented ? 3 : 0)
                .disabled(isPresented)
            HStack {
                viewForPresentation
            }
            .opacity(isPresented ? 1 : 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Now I would like to use it within another view the following way:

```
struct ServiceEditView: View {
    @State var isPopupPresented: Bool
    @State var viewForPopupPresentation: any View

    private var firstView: some View {
            Button {
                isPopupPresented = false
            } label: {
                Text("First View")
            }
    }
    
    private var secondView: some View {
            Button {
                isPopupPresented = false
            } label: {
                Text("Second View")
            }
    }

    var body: some View {
        PopupView(isPresented: $isPopupPresented, viewForPresentation: $viewForPopupPresentation) {
            // ❌ Type 'any View' cannot conform to 'View'
            HStack {
                Button {
                    viewForPopupPresentation = firstView
                    isPopupPresented = true
                } label: {
                    Text("1st")
                }
                Button {
                    viewForPopupPresentation = secondView
                    isPopupPresented = true
                } label: {
                    Text("2nd")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible at all to present another View using Binding to property of View Type?

I would like to use the same one single mechanizm to present different view depending on where it comes from.

Comment: `View` have to be concrete types `some View` you can use an `enum` instead with options.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach doesn't look to follow a "state" approach.
In general, you should control what's in your `body` based on a state, while you're storing a view you want to show in a property (`var viewForPopupPresentation: any View`).

`SwiftUI` does already something similar: presenting a new Sheet using `.sheet(item:content:)` modifier. So I'd do something very similar for your case.

First I'd create a `PopupModifier`.

```swift
struct PopupModifier<PopupView, Item>: ViewModifier where PopupView: View {
  @Binding var item: Item?
  
  var popupView: (Item) -> PopupView
  
  private var isPresented: Bool { item != nil }
  
  func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
      content
        .blur(radius: isPresented ? 3 : 0)
        .disabled(isPresented)
      if let item {
        popupView(item)
      }
      // you don't need any opacity modifier here, the view appears only if item is not nil
    }
  }
}

extension View {
  // just a syntactic sugar to apply the modifier, just like SwiftUI does
  func popup<PopupView, Item>(
    item: Binding<Item?>,
    @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Item) -> PopupView
  ) -> some View where PopupView: View {
    modifier(PopupModifier(item: item, popupView: content))
  }
}
```

Now, we can use the modifier very similar to the `sheet` one.

```swift
struct ServiceEditView: View {
  enum ViewToShow {
    case first
    case second
  }
  // the source of truth of your popup. When value is nil, no popup is shown
  @State var viewToShow: ViewToShow?
  
  private var firstView: some View {
    Button {
      viewToShow = nil
    } label: {
      Text("First View")
    }
  }
  
  private var secondView: some View {
    Button {
      viewToShow = nil
    } label: {
      Text("Second View")
    }
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    HStack {
      Button {
        viewToShow = .first
      } label: {
        Text("1st")
      }
      Button {
        viewToShow = .second
      } label: {
        Text("2nd")
      }
    }
    // apply the modifier, the closure will take your unwrapped item
    // and you can use it to decide which view will be returned
    .popup(item: $viewToShow) { viewToShow in
      switch viewToShow {
      case .first: firstView
      case .second: secondView
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, you are completely right. I messed up some things here. It should not be like that. Thanks for that.

Comment: If you think I helped can you set my answer as best?

Comment: Your answer is correct I think, but it is not useful for me because it is not a good approach to do it that way.

Comment: What you mean it's not a good approach?